# insert multiple values in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php i'm trying to insert multiple values in database.I wrote my functions but it's throwing an error.I have attached my html form below.How can i solve this...

error showing:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: itemNo
Filename: controllers/main.php
Line Number: 2406
```

My Code:

```
public function item_save(){
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("inventory", $con);
    //$id_number = $_GET['id_user'];
    $val1=$_GET['itemNo'];
    $val2=$_GET['itemName'];
    $val3=$_GET['quantity'];
    $val4=$_GET['price'];
    $val5=$_GET['total'];
    $val6=$_GET['subTotal'];
    $val7=$_GET['tax'];
    $val8=$_GET['taxAmount'];
    $val9=$_GET['totalAftertax'];
    $val10=$_GET['amountPaid'];
    $val1=$_GET['amountDue'];
    $N = count($val1);
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO item_save(item_no,item_name,qty,price,total,subtotal,tax,tax_amount,total_final,amount_paid,amount_due) VALUES ('$val1[$i]','$val2[$i]','$val3[$i]','$val4[$i]','$val5[$i]','$val6','$val7','$val8','$val9','$val10','$val11')");
    }
    redirect("main/multiple");

        }
```

form.html

```
 <div class="container content">
    <?php

echo form_open_multipart('main/item_save');


?>
        <?php


$submit=array(

    'name'=>'submit',
    'type'=>'submit',
    'class'=>'btn btn-primary',
    'value'=>'Submit',

);
?>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12'>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="2%"><input id="check_all" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox"/></th>
                            <th width="15%">Item No</th>
                            <th width="38%">Item Name</th>
                            <th width="15%">Price</th>
                            <th width="15%">Quantity</th>
                            <th width="15%">Total</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
                            <td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                            <td><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                            <td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                            <td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total_1" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" type="button">- Delete</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success addmore" type="button">+ Add More</button>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5'>
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Subtotal: &nbsp;</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="subTotal" name="subTotal" placeholder="Subtotal" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Tax: &nbsp;</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="tax" name="tax" placeholder="Tax" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Tax Amount: &nbsp;</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="taxAmount" name="taxAmount" placeholder="Tax" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Total: &nbsp;</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="totalAftertax" name="totalAftertax" placeholder="Total" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Amount Paid: &nbsp;</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amountPaid" name="amountPaid" placeholder="Amount Paid" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Amount Due: &nbsp;</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                                                        <input type="number" class="form-control amountDue" id="amountDue" name="amountDue" placeholder="Amount Due" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
             <?php echo form_submit($submit);?>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Is item_no is your primary id

Comment: Do not use`deprecated `mysqli_*` API. Use `mysqli_` or pdo with prepared statements.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, there's no `$_GET['itemNo']`. Did you post your form with `method=GET` or `method=POST`? If it's `POST`, then you need to use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.

Comment: yes item_no is primary

Comment: @NarendraSisodia What difference does that make? It's getting a PHP error from `$_GET['itemNo']`, not a MySQL error.

Comment: @Barmar I think there might be same itemNo he may try to insert if I'm wrong then correct me

Comment: @NarendraSisodia But that won't cause this error message. `Undefined index` happens when you try to access a nonexistent element of an array.

Comment: Please post the HTML of the form.

Comment: ok i am posting html form

Comment: @Jens well I knew what you meant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Notice: Undefined index: itemNo` means that your `$_GET['itemNo'];` is not set.

You probably forgot to add `&itemNo=xxx` in your URL, but looking to the rest of your code you are missing `itemNo[]` GET parameter from form (I guess checkboxes).

**EDIT:**
Now, after you posted HTML, and I still don't see `<form>` tag, let me ask you. Are you sure you are using `GET` method? Because multipart forms are usually using `POST` method.

Check your HTML output (as source code in browser), or some network debugging and check wether it's POST or GET. I bet that it's POST, but you try to retrieve GET.

Also, you can try change `$_GET` to `$_REQUEST` (matches both GET and POST), but that's not the best idea.

Comment: It should be `&itemNo[]=xxx` since he's accessing it as an array.

Comment: If he's submitting a form, the browser does this automatically.

Comment: Yes, forgot about that. Unless we see HTML it's hard to say what happened. Anyway, notice comes from `$_GET['itemNo']` so it's probably completely missing.

Comment: i have attached my form. itemNo is there its not missing.

Comment: @JunoJabin it **is** missing. From request sent to server. I mean that request sent does not have `GET itemNo[]` attached. Probably doesn't have anything or have `POST itemNo[]`. Check my edit.